# How to disable "touch ID activated" alert everytime log in to app?

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

I currently have touchID in my app and it's currently working properly.  It's a bit annoying every time you log in the "touchID activated"  alert pops up.  Is there a way to change it so it only pops up the first time logging in and not again?  Here is my code for touch ID, I call the checkIfTouchIDActivated() in viewDidLoad of the login screen:

```
 // MARK: TouchID

  //Create a authentication context
  let authenticationContext = LAContext()
  var error:NSError?


  //Check if the device has a fingerprint sensor, if not, dismiss
  func checkIfTouchIDActivated () {

    guard authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) else {
      print("TouchID not detected")
      return
    }
    print("TouchID detected")

    //Check the fingerprint
    authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(
      .DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
      localizedReason: "TouchID activated",
      reply: { [unowned self] (success, error) -> Void in

        //fingerprint has been recognized
        if( success ){

          self.loginButtonPressed(self)

        }else {

          // Check if there is an error
          if let error = error {

            let message = self.touchID.errorMessageForLAErrorCode(error.code)
            self.showAlertViewAfterEvaluatingPolicyWithMessage(message)

          }

        }

      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've given `"TouchID activated"` as the `localizedReason`. Just give a `""` if you don't want to show the user why you want to authenticate him for. It is usually like `"Are you the device owner?"`, or `"Sign in with your touch-ID"` indicating the reason as to why you are requesting `touch-id` authentication from the user.